# Twilio send sms to a list with 100+ numbers. Twilio throwing 11200 Error

Tags: c#, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

I have made a controller that sends a message to a list specified in an incoming message. 
When I'm finished sending out all the messages, I want to return a TwiML response.

However, if the list is too big it looks like Twilio is timing out.
If the list contains 10 numbers a response is returned, if it contains 40 numbers Twilio then shows me a 11200 error in the dashboard.

The outgoing message is always sent, its just the response that fails.

I have done something like this:

```
foreach (var receiver in receivers)
{
    try
    {
        await MessageResource.CreateAsync(
            from: new PhoneNumber(SomeGroupName),
            to: new PhoneNumber(receiver.Mobile),
            body: SomeOutgoingMessage);
    } 
    catch (SomeException e)
    {
        //Errorhandling
    }
}
response.Message("Message sent to all members")
return TwiML(response);
```

Do anyone know why this is happening? Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Twilio will wait 15 seconds for a response from your application. If your app takes longer than 15 seconds, [Twilio will record an 11200 error](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/11200). In your case, it takes less than 15 seconds to send the message to 10 numbers, but for 40 numbers it takes longer.

If all the messages are the same, then I can recommend using Twilio Notify to send them all with just one API request. I wrote up a blog post on [how to send bulk SMS messages with Twilio and Node.js](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/12/send-bulk-sms-twilio-node-js.html). I know you're using C#, but that is worth reading for the explanation and walkthrough.

The code you would use to [send bulk SMS with C#](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/notify/rest/notifications?code-sample=code-send-a-notification-with-bindings-in-request&code-language=cs&code-sdk-version=5.x) should look a bit like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Twilio;
using Twilio.Rest.Notify.V1.Service;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Find your Account SID and Auth Token at twilio.com/console
        const string accountSid = "your_account_sid";
        const string authToken = "your_auth_token";
        const string serviceSid = "your_messaging_service_sid";

        TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);

        var notification = NotificationResource.Create(
            serviceSid,
            toBinding: new List<string> { "{\"binding_type\":\"sms\",\"address\":\"+15555555555\"}",
            "{\"binding_type\":\"sms\",\"address\":\"+123456789123\"}" },
            body: "Hello Bob");

        Console.WriteLine(notification.Sid);
    }
}
```

Let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: I think this will do the trick. All the messages are alike :)

Comment: Sweet, sounds like the right solution then. Give me a shout if there's anything else I can help with.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/11200

Looks like it's taking Twilio longer to perform the action than your app is willing to wait for it to perform that action.